# PHP + MYSQL filtro de arquivos

Tags: php, mysql, path, id

Boa tarde esse é o meu primeiro post aqui, então ja peço desculpas se estou repetindo uma pergunta,vamos ao erro tenho uma aplicação de cadastro que estou tentando implementar upload de arquivo,abaixo segue o codigo PHP que  esta fazendo a função correta:

```
<?php
//conectar ao BD.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gestao-unical");
if($conn) {
//conexao estabelecida.
echo "conectado";
}
//se o botão com o nome SendCadImg foi clicado
if(isset($_POST['SendCadImg'])) {
//declarando as variaveis
$filename = $_FILES['arquivos']['name'];
$filetmpname = $_FILES['arquivos']['tmp_name'];
$idEvento = $_POST['campoIDEVENTO'];
//pasta para onde vai os arquivos
$folder = 'arquivos/';
//função para salvar as imagens carregadas em uma pasta específica
move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $folder.$filename);
//insert da imagem (nome da imagem) no banco de dados
$sql = "INSERT INTO `uploadedimage` (`imagename`,`idEvento`)  VALUES ('$filename','$idEvento')";
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,  $sql);
if( $qry) {
echo "</br>image uploaded"; 
}
}
?>
```

para listar os arquivos uso o codigo abaixo, porem sem referencia ao que foi gravado no MYSQL

```
<?php
$pasta = 'arquivos/';

if(is_dir($pasta))
{
$diretorio = dir($pasta);

while(($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false)
{
echo '<a href='.$pasta.$arquivo.'>'.$arquivo.'</a><br />';
}

$diretorio->close();
}
else
{
echo 'A pasta não existe.';
}
?>
```

como aproveitar o insert e listar os arquivos pelo ID gerado no banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que eu entendi você gostaria de listar os nomes das imagens gravadas para o usuário clicar e abrir a imagem.

Nesta caso você faria uma consulta simples no Banco e listaria os resultados
De modo simples ficaria assim:

```
//Monta a pasta e valida se a mesma existe
$pasta = 'arquivos/';
if(!is_dir($pasta)){
   //caso não exista escreve a mensagem e para o codigo
   echo 'A pasta não existe.';
   exit;
}

//Sql e a função para executalo
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uploadimagens";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Le os registros retornados na consulta
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<a href='{$pasta}{$row['imagename']}'>{$row['imagename']} {$row['idEvento']}</a><br />";
}
```

Comment: valeu pela resposta , voce compreendeu o que desejo fazer , peguei o seu código porem não compreendi o wile , tentei usa-lo e não retorna nada na tela.

Comment: Me desculpe tente substituir o `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` por `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` e não esquece de incluir a conexão com o Mysql no inicio do programa. O while é para ler todos os registros que retornarem na sua consulta, pois ela pode retornar mais de uma linha

Answer (score -1):

você pode fazer uma consulta ao DB com:

```sql
 QUERY * FROM `uploadedimage`SORT BY `nome_da_chave_primaria`
```

Faz a query, armazena em uma array com `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Depois itera em cima da array mostrando os dados do jeito que você pretende.

A grosso modo pode ficar algo assim:

```php
$sql = "QUERY * FROM `uploadedimage`SORT BY `nome_da_chave_primaria`";
$qry = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);

while ($arr) {
 echo $arr['imagename'] . " " . $arr['idEvento'];
}
```

Comment: não entendi como proceder